# Can you calculate the password hash used by Active Directory?

Tags: .net, active-directory, password-encryption

We currently store users of our web application in our database, along with hashes/salts of their passwords. The hashes are calculated when the user is created and sets their password and stored in a User table in a database.

Some time after the creation of the user account, we may want to create a windows account in our domain, and want to be able to set the domain user's password so that it's the same as the one the user uses to log into the web app. Since we don't save the plain text version of the password, we don't have a way to send it to AD when we created it.

One way I was thinking about getting around this issue, would be to calculate all the different password hashes that AD uses when the user first sets their password, and then somehow set the records in AD later when we create the user.

1. How would you create the hashes (I think they are MD4, MD5, and DES), using .Net?
2. Can you bypass the password creation on UserPrincpal.SetPassword, and make some other call in order to directly set the hashes stored by AD?

It seems like there should be a way to do this, since MS has tools for sync'ing passwords from AD to Azure users.

Comment: Interesting question, but I think this will only work if you use the same salt as Windows ?!? And from a security perspective: is it a good idea to have the same password on both systems ? I would say what you are looking for is a single sign on solution

Comment: The issue is, as far as I know, Windows doesn't play well with single sign on, unless it is the "single" point for sign on. Somehow MS has tools to sync passwords, so I believe it must be possible.

Comment: Depending on where your web application is running at you can use SSO with various techniques: SAML, Kerberos, certificates. But keep trying to get the syncing approach implemented and don't forget the security implications this might have. The first S in SSO sometimes is more for "silent" than single ;-)

Comment: AD to Azure accesses the replication APIs and extracts the password hashes from AD, rehashes them, and then sends them up to Azure AD over an encrypted channel. There isn't a way to push the hashes in to AD after the fact that would really count as a remotely supported manner.

Comment: Brian, I'm not sure what you mean by "would really count as a remotely supported manner"

Comment: Also, for password sync to work, Azure would have to be using the same hashing algo as AD, so I'm not sure how it could rehash them.

Answer (score 5):

Trying to keep an AD password synchronized with a DB password is a bad idea for two reasons:

- It's a security weakness (comments have already pointed this out by mentioning salt)
- It's a maintenance problem.  A password change initiated by the windows PC would leave the DB password unchanged.

Instead of creating a windows account with the same password, alter your web application's authentication to use *both* AD authentication and Windows Forms authentication.  That way, their AD credentials (if they have them) will superseded the username/password prompt.

Comment: Yes. Op can set a flag in the database once an AD account has been created. Then use this flag to determine whether to authenticate against the database or against the AD. One very easy way to authenticate against AD (*when used responsibly and securely*) is the [PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.validatecredentials(v=vs.110).aspx) of the [AccountManagement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement(v=vs.110).aspx) class. +1 for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding holding a) an encrypted password you can get cleartext back for, b) a weak hash, are both bad ideas in case the DB is compromised by an internal/external attacker.

You could consider a different approach: 
* create the AD account for the user with a long, random, unknown password. Put an 'ADPasswordLastSet=null' timestamp on the account. 
* next time that user signs into your web app, after authenticating them, you have the password in the clear so set the AD user's password to the same. Don't forget to update the ADPasswordLastSet flag.

You therefore don't have to write the password anywhere if you can set it synchronously.

One thing to remember: password complexity policies - you want to make sure that the policy present in the UI that the user interacts with has the more stringent policy.